# Computing the local $\gamma$-factor for the local zeta integral (Goldfeld-Hundley)

Tags: automorphic-forms, langlands-program

Let $\nu \leq \infty$ and $\mathbb{Q}_\nu$ denote a local field. Suppose $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(s) > 0$. Let $\Phi: \mathbb{Q}_\nu \to \mathbb{C}$ be a Schwartz-Bruhat function. Let $\omega : \mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ be a local unitary character. Defining
$$Z_\nu(s, \Phi, \omega) := \int_{\mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times} \Phi(x) \omega(x) |x|_\nu^s \, d^\times x$$ as the local integral associated to $\omega$ and $\Phi$.

Question 1: Is the following proof for the convergence of following integral correct?
Suppose $\Re(s) >0$ as $\Phi$ has compact support then there exists $0 < K,M < \infty$ so that
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times \\ |x|_\nu >1}} \Phi(x) \omega(x) |x|_\nu^s \, d^\times x\right| &=\left| \int_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times \\ 1<|x|_\nu\leq K }}\Phi(x) \omega(x) |x|_\nu^s \, d^\times x \right|\\
&\leq \int_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times \\ 1<|x|_\nu\leq K }} M K^{\Re(s)} \, d^\times x\\
&\leq \mu\{1 < |x|_\nu \leq K\} M K^{\Re(s)}\\ &<\infty
\end{align*}
where $\mu$ denotes the Haar measure on the multiplicative group on $\mathbb{Q}_\nu^\times$.

Question 2 (Page 59): Suppose $\nu = p$, a finite prime $p$ and $\omega$ is ramified with conductor $p^r$. Defining $\Phi^\circ(x) := e^{- 2 \pi i\{x\}}$ if $x \in p^{-r} \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $0$ otherwise. Where
$$\{x\} := \begin{cases} \sum_{i=-k}^{-1} a_i p^i &\ \text{if}\ x = \sum_{i=-k}^\infty a_i p^i \in \mathbb{Q}_p\\ 0 & \ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
Then,
\begin{align}
Z_p(s, \Phi^\circ, \omega) &= \frac{p}{p-1} \int_{p^{-r} \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}} e^{- 2\pi i\{x\}} \omega(x) |x|_p^s \frac{dx}{|x|_p}\\
&= \frac{p}{p-1} \sum_{l=1}^r \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ (j,p) = 1}}^{p^r} \int_{p^{-l}(j + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p)} e^{- 2\pi i\{x\}} \omega(x) |x|_p^s \frac{dx}{|x|_p}\\
&= p^{-r} \frac{p}{p-1} \sum_{l=1}^r p^{ls} \omega(p)^{-l} \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ (j,p) =1}}^{p^r} e^{- \frac{2 \pi i j}{p^l}} \omega(j)\\
&= \frac{p^{-r + 1}}{p-1} p^{rs} \omega(p)^{-r} \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ (j,p) =1}}^{p^r} e^{- \frac{2 \pi i j}{p^l}} \omega(j).
\end{align}

1. How do you obtain the decomposition of $p^{-r}\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}$ to obtain the Gauss sum?
2. Why does $\sum_{\substack{j=1\\ (j,p) =1}}^{p^r} e^{- \frac{2 \pi i j}{p^l}} \omega(j) =0$ whenever $l < r$?

Question 3: Assuming that
$$\widehat{\Phi^\circ}(x) := \begin{cases} p^r& \text{if}\ x \in 1 + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Then,
\begin{align}
Z_p(1-s, \widehat{\Phi^\circ}, \overline{\omega}) &= p^r \frac{p}{p-1} \int_{1 + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p} \overline{\omega(x)} |x|_p^{1-s} \frac{dx}{|x|_p}\\
&= p^r \frac{p}{p-1}\int_{1 + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p} \frac{dx}{|x|_p}\\
&= \frac{p}{p-1}.
\end{align}

1. Is there is mistake in this computation? As I believe it should be compute as follows
   $$Z_p(1-s, \widehat{\Phi^\circ}, \overline{\omega}) = p^r \frac{p}{p-1} \int_{1 + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p} \overline{\omega(x)} |x|_p^{1-s} \frac{dx}{|x|_p} = p^r \frac{p}{p-1} \int_{1 + p^r \mathbb{Z}_p} \frac{dx}{|x|_p^s} = p^r \cdot \frac{p}{p-1} p^{rs} p^{-r} = \frac{p}{p-1} p^{rs}.$$

Source: Goldfeld-Hundley, automorphic representations and $L$-functions for the general linear group (Pg 55-60).